# center div inside column bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to center a form inside a column in bootstrap. Is it possible because I'm searching for more than an hour and still found nothing. I'm a novice in bootstrap...

My code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!--Row with two equal columns-->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">

        <form class="form-inline row" role="form" action="index.php" method="post">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="kerkim" id="input_main" value="">

                <i id="slash">|</i>

                <div class="input-group">

                <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" >
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="text" class="btn btn-warning"><i>Me gjej</i></button>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second left</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second right</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use offset value in form `col-md-offset-4`

```
<form class="form-inline row col-md-offset-4" method="post" action="index.php" role="form">
```

For more detail go with **[LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)**

Answer (score 3):

add a class to form "center_form"

```
    <form class="form-inline row center_form" role="form" action="index.php" method="post">
```

and add below css

```
    .center_form{margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove class row from your form element, as it contains no columns. Next, you need to use css to center your form.
Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!--Row with two equal columns-->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">

        <form class="form-inline centered" role="form" action="index.php" method="post">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="kerkim" id="input_main" value="">

                <i id="slash">|</i>

                <div class="input-group">

                <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" >
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="text" class="btn btn-warning"><i>Me gjej</i></button>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second left</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second right</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.centered {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this html layout to accomplish a centered form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!--Row with two equal columns-->

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline centered col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" role="form" action="index.php" method="post">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="kerkim" id="input_main" value="">

                <i id="slash">|</i>

                <div class="input-group">

                <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" >
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="text" class="btn btn-warning"><i>Me gjej</i></button>
                </div>
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second left</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Second right</h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```